# Excel Gantt chart format date after week number on axis

Tags: excel, date, formatting

I have a sheet of processes all mapped to starting dates and ending dates, that are used to generate a Gantt chart. However, instead of dates formatted as "MM/DD/YYYY" on the X-axis, I want the year and week number ("YY/WW"). I haven't been able to find anything on this. Could it be done in the excel interface, or at the very least programmatically in VBA (Which I have very little experience in)?

Comment: It can be done with a formula, that returns text, but that result would not be able to be used in other calcs unless parsed.

Comment: weeknumber is not a date format option in Excel.  So you would have to create your labels differently -- eg text string in Excel; or possibly custom formatting with VBA.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick answers. I tried building a column in the dataset with the appropriate text, but it resulted in other issues. Could you elaborate on these solutions you are telling me about?

Comment: Provide examples of what you have tried, and your data.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in Cell A1 this will build a week number and year number as you have described. The left side simply grabs the year with a function and only takes the last 2 digits. The right side returns the day of the year out of 365 then divides to get a week number, then formats the text to include insignificant zeros to preserve the WW format.

=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(YEAR(A1),2),"/",TEXT(CEILING((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0))/7,1),"00"))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this approach doesn't work in the chart, since the data used will be formatted as strings, which breaks the linearity of the chart (The "number" after 1752 should be 1801). I need to keep the Date data type, or create a custom format.